# tell Postfix to close connection right after "Relay access denied"

Tags: postfix

I have seen on some good setup mail servers, they terminate connection right after error

```
454 4.7.1 <spammer@spamserver.com>: Relay access denied
```

which is probably saving a lot of resources and traffic. And my Postfix still keeps SMTP session opened for future commands, whose, probably, are going to be only spam.

How can I tell Postfix to terminate session (like those smart servers) right after this error was given to the spammer?

### Info

- Postfix version 2.10.1
- Output of `postconf -n`

  ```
  [root@mail ~]# postconf -n
  config_directory = /etc/postfix
  header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_check
  inet_protocols = ipv4
  local_recipient_maps =
  mydestination = example.com, $myhostname, localhost.$myhostname, $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain
  mydomain = example.com
  myhostname = mail.example.com
  mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/16
  myorigin = example.com
  relay_domains = example.com
  smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
  smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
      permit_mynetworks, 
      reject_unauth_destination, 
      reject_invalid_hostname, 
      reject_unauth_pipelining, 
      reject_non_fqdn_sender, 
      reject_unknown_recipient_domain, 
      reject_unknown_sender_domain, 
      check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
  smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
      check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipients,
      reject_non_fqdn_sender,
      reject_rhsbl_sender blackhole.securitysage.com,
      reject_unknown_sender_domain
  transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have good and bad news for you regarding this question.

**The good news** is Postfix indeed has a mechanism to disconnect when a client is misbehaving. It is documented on [this page](http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html#slowdown). Three parameters control the behavior: [smtpd_soft_error_limit](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_soft_error_limit), [smtpd_hard_error_limit](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_hard_error_limit), [smtpd_error_sleep_time](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_error_sleep_time). This pseudocode will illustrate how it works.

```
While smtpd get connection from client
    error_counter = 0

    if there ERROR* in SMTP transaction
        error_counter = error_counter + 1

    if error_counter > $smtpd_soft_error_limit
        show the error message with delay $smtpd_soft_error_delay
    else if error_counter > $smtpd_hard_error_limit
        DISCONNECT client
    else
        show the error message IMMEDIATELY

    if one message transfered successfully
        error_counter = 0 //reset the counter
```

*Note: In postfix terms, `ERROR*` is triggered when a client request is unrecognized or unimplemented, when a client request violates access restrictions, or when some other error happens.*

See, if we set the `smtpd_hard_error_limit` with 1, postfix will happily to disconnect the client when error happened.

**The bad news** is we can't filter which error that triggered smtpd_hard_error_limit. Your intention to limit this disconnect-behavior to `Relay Access Denied` error can't be implemented. After you set `smtpd_hard_error_limit` to 1, every error like

```
Recipient access rejected, user not Found
```

or

```
Sender address rejected: Domain not found;
```

will result of disconnected client. [The postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/STRESS_README.html#adapt) states some effect when `smtpd_hard_error_limit = 1`.

> Under conditions of stress, use an smtpd_hard_error_limit of 1 instead of the default 20. This helps by disconnecting clients after a single error, giving other clients a chance to connect. However, this may cause significant delays with legitimate mail, such as a mailing list that contains a few no-longer-active user names that didn't bother to unsubscribe. No mail should be lost, as long as this measure is used only temporarily.

---

#### Alternative solution

For the alternative solution for zombie-like client, you can [enable postscreen in postfix](http://www.postfix.org/STRESS_README.html#other). Postscreen will add one layer to smtpd process so the server should deal with legitimate client. See the documentations in [here](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html) and [here](http://www.postfix.org/postscreen.8.html)

---

#### Why my server show error 4XX instead 5XX?

Postfix 2.10 introduces one parameter called `smtpd_relay_restriction`. You can read the documentation in [postconf(5)](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions). By default this parameter has values

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
    permit_mynetworks 
    permit_sasl_authenticated 
    defer_unauth_destination
```

Parameter `defer_unauth_destination` will throw error 4xx instead 5xx.

The best advice is split the restriction in two parameter smtpd_relay_restriction and smtpd_recipient_restriction. However if you insist to keep old config (e.g. in smtpd_recipient_restriction only), you can set smtpd_relay_restriction empty in `main.cf`

```
smtpd_relay_restriction =
```